# Adds integration with addmob without bank Details

Tags: android

I am developing an android game in which I wanted to integrate the ads. Is there a way in which I can integrate the ads for testing purpose without giving out my bank details during the registration of the account at Admob?
It seems as if giving out the bank details is necessary ?

Comment: That's logic no ? This is the first step in order to add ads in your apps ;-) You have nothing to lose by entering your details during the development.

Comment: yea but what if I havn't created the bank account and wanted to complete the development ? :)